# Dynamic ForEach loop to update object Property value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the code below that I need some help fixing please. What I want to, is pass a String Expression, and a String[] Parameter to this method, and have the Expression compiled and applied to the individual items in the list.

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IList<T> source, string expression, params object[] values)
  {
       if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
       if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
       var enumerableList = source.AsEnumerable<T>();

        return (from T item in source
            select (T) DynamicLambdaExpression.ParseLambda(item.GetType(), typeof(T), expression, values).Compile().DynamicInvoke(item));


  }
```

As is, the expression is probably being applied but the type returned from each operation is not the type that I expect. Not sure since I get an exception when I run it.

```
<IfTrue Expression="it.UID = @0 + it.index.ToString(@1)" Parameters="000000 D6"/>
```

The error message I keep getting says

**System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Expression of type 'IProductDetail' expected
  Source=Dynamic
  Position=0
  StackTrace: at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType)**

So, I would appreciate any help in fixing the code, and explaining what I have done wrong please. thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Don't re-compile the expression for each item in the list.

Comment: This is more of a `Select` operation (mapping) than a `ForEach` if you have a return type.  Your return type would be based off what you pass in expression...

Comment: In your case, what is the type of T here? IProductDetail? and what is the concrete object type ? T could be an interface while item.GetType() returns the concrete type. add code for your client call here

Comment: isn't the first parameter to ParseLambda supposed to be the **type of the lambda expression itself**?

Comment: I believe the problem is that the expression itself does not compile correctly. I am using Dynamic.dll by the way.

Comment: @Kobojunkie, obviously, yet the reason why the parse fails might well be because you're indicating a totally wrong expected type.

Comment: You see the expression and the code above. What unexpected type are you referring to?

Comment: @Kobojunkie, *the type of the lambda expression expected from ParseLambda, as (mis-)specified in its first parameter*

Comment: Can you please point out the particular type that was mis-specified please? I am having a hard time understanding you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading the data directly from the Xml and passing it to your function without modification, then you're only passing one parameter. The values array would look like this:

```
values[0] : "000000 D6"
```

You might need to split the value of your parameter in the xml based on a known delimiter that is not likely to exist as an actual value, such as a pipe, like so: `"000000|D6"`. Then, you can change that into an array of parameters using split: `var parms = string.Split(values, "|");`. (You **could** use the space character for this, but that might cause more trouble later on depending on the values you have in this attribute.)

So if you're only passing one item in to your `values` parameter, then `values[1]` will be `null` (or more accurately, non-existent), and that could be causing the exception you're seeing. It's hard to know what's actually happening without seeing the rest of your code, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: That does not seem to resolve the issue please. I don't think the problem is in dissecting the string, but in assigning the value to the property, and returning an IProductDetail object afterwards.